# Why isn't the js image object garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, image, reference, garbage-collection

I'm coming from a c++ background and learning javascript. The Mozilla tutorials on webgl have code similar to below (actual code and link at bottom). I am trying to understand why the code in the "onload" callback function will always be executed. It seems to me that the Image object instance should be garbage collected in the code below. So it theoretically can be garbage collected before the load completes and calls the "onload" callback.

```
function foo()
{
  image = new Image();

  image.onload = function()
  {
     /*stuff to do when image gets done loading */
    Console.log(image.width);
  }

  image.src = url;
}
```

The only idea I have is that the function that uses "image.width" -- the function object must be keeping the image instance in memory. But that would be a circle reference because that function only exists on the image object itself; the function object's only reference AFAIK is its onload callback property. So the circular reference (image->onload->function->image->...) should be garbage collected.

It seems I am do not understand something, or there is a race condition between the image loading and when it is garbage collected.

JS Reference showing circular reference islands no longer reachable should be garbage collected. https://javascript.info/garbage-collection

Tutorials Link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Using_textures_in_WebGL

```
function loadTexture(gl, url) {
  const texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  // Put a single pixel in the texture until it loads
  const level = 0;  const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;  const width = 1;  const height = 1;  const border = 0;  const srcFormat = gl.RGBA;  const srcType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;  const pixel = new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]);  // opaque blue
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,width, height, border, srcFormat, srcType, pixel);

  const image = new Image();

  image.onload = function() {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,srcFormat, srcType, image);

    // WebGL1 has different requirements for power of 2 images vs non power of 2 images so check if the image is a power of 2 in both dimensions.
    if (isPowerOf2(image.width) && isPowerOf2(image.height)) {
       gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D); // Yes, it's a power of 2. Generate mips.
    } else {
       // No, it's not a power of 2. Turn off mips and set wrapping to clamp to edge
       gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
       gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
       gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    }
  };
  image.src = url;

  return texture;
}

//irrelevant, but including for completeness
function isPowerOf2(value)
{
    return (value & (value - 1)) == 0
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign to `image.src`, the `Image` obect is added to an internal queue of the browser for all external objects that are being loaded asynchronously. This queue prevents the object from becoming garbage immediately when the function returns. The queue is necessary just for the browser to manage the process of loading these objects -- it needs to save the objects being loaded, so it knows what to do when it gets the response from the server.

When the image is loaded, its `onload` function is added to the event queue, and since it has a reference to the object through the `image` variable (and also the `this` context of the function, and the `Event` argument to the function), that keeps the object alive while the function is running.

Once the `onload` function returns, the image will become garbage (since it doesn't save the value of `image` anywhere).

Comment: A brilliant answer. Thank you